# Iterating through a list of tickers is not wokring properly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following Google Sheet:

```
      A         B
 1  Ticker  Last Update
 2  MMM
 3  AOS
 4  ABT
 5  ABBV
 6  ACN
 7  ATVI
 8  ADM
 9  ADBE
10  ADP
11  AAP
12  AES
13  AFL
14  A
15  APD
16  AKAM
17  ALK
18  ALB
19  ARE
20  ALGN
21  ALLE
22  LNT
23  ALL
24  GOOGL
```

Eventually, this has to become a stock watchlist but for now I am retrieving no stock data but am ust focussing on the general working.

The general working that I want is as follows:

1. A function that takes 10 tickers at a time (10 tickers = a "batch")
2. For each ticker in the batch, fill in the current date and time of processing in column B
3. Move on to the next 10, until at script reaches the end of the tickers in A
4. For the last tickers, do not take a batch of 10, but a batch of whatever tickers are left (in the example above, this would be 3 tickers (`A22` to `A24`) that are left
5. Once the end of the list is reached, start again from the top
6. The function is invoked every minute by a trigger on the Google sheet

I now have the following script:

```
function trackStockData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var tickers = sheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues().filter(String); // Filter out empty cells
  var batchCount = 10;
  var startRow = Number(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("startRow")) || 2;
  var lastBatchRow = sheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues().filter(String).length;
  var tickersProcessed = lastBatchRow - 2; // Number of tickers already processed
  var remainingTickers = tickers.length - tickersProcessed;
  var batchSize = Math.min(batchCount, remainingTickers);

  if (remainingTickers <= 0) {
    // All tickers have been processed
    return;
  }

  var batchTickers = tickers.slice(tickersProcessed, tickersProcessed + batchSize);

  // Write date and time of retrieval to column B starting from cell B2
  var dateTime = new Date();
  var dateTimeValues = new Array(batchSize).fill([dateTime]);
  var range = sheet.getRange(startRow, 2, batchSize, 1);
  range.setValues(dateTimeValues);

  // Update the starting row for the next batch
  startRow += batchSize;
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("startRow", startRow.toString());
}
```

I experience 2 problems with this script and am hoping for some help:

1. The script does not take the last 3 tickers in the third batch. Instead, it takes cells `A22` to `A26`, even though there is no ticker in `A25` and `A26`. How can I make it take the correct number of tickers?
2. The script stops once it reaches the end of the list. How do I make it go back to the top and start again?

For people who like to use a sample sheet: see my example and code [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xl6igie7p9ot75pyA4fCQv7QTZxwV0DM-iVWT4HdIdw/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: It looks like @Tanaike provided a great answer, is the answer achieving your expected result @Pr0no?

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result from your question, is the following sample script your expected result?

#### Sample script:

```js
function trackStockData() {
  var limit = 10; // This is from your question.

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:B" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var values = range.getValues();
  var ar = values.slice();
  var splitted = [...Array(Math.ceil(ar.length / limit))].map((_) => ar.splice(0, limit));
  var topValue = values[0][1] && values[0][1].toString();
  var endValue = values[values.length - 1][1] && values[values.length - 1][1].toString();
  var idx = (!topValue || endValue) ? 0 : splitted.findIndex(g => !g.every(([, b]) => b && b.toString()));
  if (idx == 0) {
    splitted = splitted.map(g => g.map(([a]) => [a, null]));
  }
  var dateTime = new Date();
  var updatedValues = splitted.flatMap((g, i) => g.map(([a, b]) => i == idx ? [a, dateTime] : [a, b]));
  range.setValues(updatedValues);

  var batchTickers = splitted[idx].map(([a]) => a);
  console.log(batchTickers); // You can confirm the retrieve value in the log.
}
```

- In this case, when `trackStockData()` is run, the columns "A" and "B" are retrieved. And, rows are split every 10 rows. And, the values of column "B" are checked, and the values of `batchTickers` are retrieved. And, the current date is put in the checked rows. Is this process your expected result?

#### Note:

- I tested this sample script using your provided Spreadsheet. When you change the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)